# Save and access a file using scoped storage in android with target SDK 30

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, scoped-storage

I am a creating a new app and want to use scoped storage for clicking a picture and and displaying on imageview using scoped storage and camerax

Please help

Comment: Wel do it. What is the problem? And nobody needs scoped storage to click a picture so why would you?

Comment: from target sdk 30 its is compulsory